# UILabel is always nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I have the following problem.

This is my Code:

```
GTSearchViewController* vc = [[GTSearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GTSearchViewController"
                                                                          bundle:nil];

vc.headlineLabel.text = [[self.categorieArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"categoryName"];

[AppDelegate().centerViewController pushViewController:vc
                                              animated:YES];
```

As you can see, I try to push a New ViewController with a xib File and want to set a String in my `headlineLabel` from my Array `self.categorieArray`. But when the `SearchController` gets pushed, everything works perfect, but my `headlineLabel` is always `nil`.

I don't understand why, I thought I don´t need to call "alloc-init" in the `SearchController` because everything is build with Interface Builder?

Comment: Your `headlineLabel` is `nil` because the controller have not loaded its view at this point. Pass a string instead and assign to your label's text property at `-viewDidLoad` time.

Comment: Could you correct with your code (the `initWithNibName:` seems not full written).

Comment: @ Alladinian Omg, that was the problem, i was totally confused...should go sleeping.. thanks man!

Comment: If your nib name is equal to your VC's classname, you may just write [GTSearchViewController new] instead of [[GTSearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"" bundle:@""]

Comment: Thanks for the Tip, didnt know that this is possible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is changing UI before it actually is loaded.

You should set label's text in ViewDidLoad of your view controller (it is called after the view is loaded).

---

Make NSString property in your SearchViewController class and set it right after initialization.

```
vc.headlineText = [[self.categorieArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"categoryName"];
```

Then in SearchViewController you should override viewDidLoad method:

```
 - (void) viewDidLoad{
       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.headlineLabel.text = self.headlineText;
    }
```

P.S. Of course I assume that you've set headlineLabel outlet correctly (from Interface Builder).

Comment: Thanks, That was the Problem! I totally forgot that i cannot change the UI before it´s actually loaded!